# What's a good web-based analytics package that'll work without requiring javascript?

Tags: myspace, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools

My understanding is that Google Analytics (the tool I'd normally use for website analytics) cannot be used on a MySpace page, because MySpace doesn't allow you to embed javascript.

But my client wants to track usage of her MySpace page.

Has anyone found away around this? I'm looking for a different web-based, third-party analytics toolset, I guess. One that doesn't depend on javascript, is at least close to as feature-rich as Google Analytics, and is preferably cheap (or free!).

(I picture a 1x1 image-based solution.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StatCounter](http://www.statcounter.com/) is a pretty good alternative to Google Analytics that provides an image-based tracking tool for this sort of situation. It does only keep track of the last 500 requests for the free plan, however.

You also have to understand that the only way to do this without Javascript (the image based approach) will not be able to collect nearly as much data as the Javascript-based tracking tools.

Answer (score 2):

AwStats is a server-side that processes based on your server logs.

Answer (score 2):

[GetClicky](http://getclicky.com/) uses an image and/or a script to track visitors.